# Study that uses efficient sample size

Tags: experiment-design

Suppose we have $10$ pairs of matched data (i.e. pre-exposure and post exposure). Call the exposure $E_1$. So the data are in the form $(\overline{x}_1, \overline{y}_1), \dots, (\overline{x}_n,\overline{y}_n)$. For example, $(\overline{x}_1, \overline{y}_1)$ is the average of measuring $E_1$ of subject $1$ 10 times pre-exposure and $10$ times post-exposure.

Suppose we have some other exposure $E_2$. We want to test whether $E_2$ is effective by itself. We also want to compare $E_2$ and $E_1$. We only have the data on $E_1$. Also we are primarily interested in $E_2$. What are some ways of reducing the sample size required for these experiments?

A crossover study seems good because each person can serve as their own control. Also the sample size for both problems would be the same.